# How to execute a function every minute while the rest of code is running

Tags: c++, function

I need to schedule a function to execute every minute while the rest of the code is running concurrently with this function in c++.

Comment: How precise and how much drift is tolerable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use threads.

Simple example:

```
void foo(){
  while(CONDITION){
    // do something
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(60s); // this function holds the foo execution for 60 sec
    // should add an exit condition or this function will non stop
  }
}

int main(){
    std::thread th(foo);

    // do somthing else

    th.join();
}
```

What happens here is while your main is doing one thing, the foo function is executing on another thread, and the main is waiting for it to end (th.join() waits for th to end).

Notice, I'm assuming your foo function execution is very short, and that's why I set the sleepfor() argument to 60 sec. You should check if it is so. You can use std::clock() to measure the time elapsed and use smaller arguments for the sleepfor()

Comment: I'd suspect for the question `// do somthing else` should appear before `th.join();`. Also busy waiting seems a not so good idea, rather use `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ of course. my mistake. About busy waiting, maybe it's not ideal, but it gets the job done.But I'll add the option you mentioned, thx

Comment: I'd pop a wait or sleep of some sort into the thread's task loop to chop up the CPU eaten by the busy spin and add an an exit condition otherwise that join is going to block for a long, long time.